# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_32 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10000,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

`x` has `shape=(33,10000,1)` and `y` has `shape=(33,10000)`.
but this error is popping out when i running the code:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_40_input to have shape (1, 10000) but got array with shape (10000, 1)`

i have tried changing the `input_shape=(10000,1)` in lstm layer but this error comes then:

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_39 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10000,)`

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

x = np.reshape(x, (33, 10000, 1))

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units=4, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1, 10000)))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

regressor.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Is 33 the number of samples you have? and 10000 the number of time steps?

Comment: yes...i have 33 images of 100*100 =10000 size...i have have converted images into 1 d arrray and created x=(33*10000)  array and passed into it

Comment: Is this a classification task? Because I am confused, each label is of size `10000` indicating you want to predict each pixel of the image? If that is the case you should wrap `TimeDistributed` around `LSTM`.

Comment: Two things to try: First, having an LSTM with input shape of (1, 10000) does not make much sense. It means that you have only 1 time step. So the history is not leveraged. Try reshaping your data so that you can pass multiple time steps into the model. Second, Flattening an image is not the best idea. Search CNN/LSTM hybrid and how you can leverage those architectures.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here, I think. As mentioned in the comments, your labels have length 10000, so it looks like you are trying to classify each pixel in your image? That's kind of strange. Also, you are using categorical cross-entropy loss, but you only have a single output value from your dense layer. If you want to use categorical cross-entropy, you should have as many output units in your final dense layer as you have classes, and probably should use softmax activation as well.

Using some dummy data that we won't be able to train anything to, but will at least tell us if we have errors. Note the targets here are either 0 or 1, so *two categories*.

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(33, 10000, 1))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(33, 10000, 1))
```

I rewrote your network to wrap `TimeDistributed()` around your dense layer, and set `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM to make sure we get its output for every step in the time series. Your input shape should be `(10000, 1)` or, in general, `(sequence_length, num_features)`. I also set the `units=2` in the dense layer and set its activation to softmax for what appears to be a classification task.

```
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units=4,
                   activation='sigmoid',
                   input_shape=(10000, 1),
                   return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=2,
                                    activation='softmax')))
```

Finally, I set your loss to *sparse* categorical cross-entropy since it looks like your labels are not the right dimension to use regular categorical cross-entropy. The sparse version just infers one-hot encoding from the integer *values* of the labels. You can try both, but I think you need this one for the sizes given.

```
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
regressor.summary()
regressor.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```

Network summary and training results:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_15 (LSTM)               (None, 10000, 4)          96        
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_10 (TimeDis (None, 10000, 2)          10        
=================================================================
Total params: 106
Trainable params: 106
Non-trainable params: 0

_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/1
33/33 [==============================] - 14s 435ms/step - loss: 0.7048
```

Comment: this error is comimg while i am running your code:```InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_4_input' with dtype float and shape [?,10000,1]
  [[{{node lstm_4_input}}]]
                                                                                                                                              
```

Comment: Strange, I can literally copy and paste my code here and run it without issue. Well, I have to add import statements that I omitted above. What's the shape of the `x` you are giving your network?

Comment: it ran on google colab ...but this error is coming..```InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 255 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).  Label values 0 0 0``` becaue my range of x is from 0 to 255 can u tell me what improvement i shall make in my code?? shape of x is ```x=np.reshape(x,(33,10000,1))```

Comment: and i want to predict 0 or 1 correspoding to every pixel (whose value ranges from 0 to 255) ..how can i do this?